# Visual Studio C++ Document Outline

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have CMake C++ projects in Visual Studio 2022 and would like to view the document outline for cpp/h files. But the Document Outline view is not available for this file type:
[image]

In VS Code, with the C++ extensions installed, there is a nice outline view:
[image]

But for various reasons, I need to use **Visual Studio** (not VS Code). I have diligently searched the extensions on Visual Studio Marketplace and found nothing that does this. It is surprising that as powerful as Visual Studio is, there is no outline view for C++ files. It seems like such an obvious feature -- I can't possibly be the only one who has ever needed it. Does anyone know of an extension for this?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong spot. In VS, open Solution Explorer, and click the `>` beside the file name

Comment: Do you want "Class View"?

Comment: @ChrisMM, there is no > beside the file name in my case. Maybe because it's a CMake project and not a traditional MSBuild project?

Comment: @drescherjm, thank you. "Class View" is somewhat helpful, but it shows everything for the entire project. I was hoping to see the outline for just the active document, just like VS Code does. This is useful it navigating around large files.